# How to write regex to check the format 999/99 server-side?

Tags: c#, regex

I would like a regular expression that validates a string to ensure that it is in the format

```
xxx/xx
```

where `x` is a digit, and `/` is a literal slash.  How should I write a regular expression that can validate this format using server-side C#?

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
\d{3}/\d{2}
```

And just for the future, if you have any regex problems you can always write and check your own here:

[RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)